# Eloquent $fillable with nested json keys

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to predefine a structure for internal POST Requests and the json structure will look similar to this:

```
{
    "name":"max",
    "prename":"maxmax",
    "friends": {
        "quantity":3
        "online":1
    }

}
```

My Model looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    protected $connection = "mongodb";
    protected $fillable = ["name", "prename", "friends"];
}
```

Based on that my Controller looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ResponseEvent;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function createUser(Request $request) {
        $user = User::create($request->all());
        return response()->json(["message"=>"created"], 201);
    }
}
```

Now it is possible to pass everything to the *friends* key and it will be stored in the database. Is it possible to define a nested json in the *$fillable* attribute of the Model or is there another effective way to make sure that only *"quantity"* and *"online"* can be stored in the database, while using:

```
$user = User::create($request->all());
```

In reality my POST-Body is much bigger and has more nested keys, so i guess it wouldn't be effective to proof each key individually.

Comment: The purpose of [`$fillable`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#mass-assignment) is to protect against unwanted mass-assignment not determine if the data being persisted to a field is valid, that would be the responsibility of [validation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation). As your `json` is custom, it will likely require a [custom validation rule(s)](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#custom-validation-rules) to achieve your goal.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to solve this with your hints.

Comment: ``$request->merge(
                [
                    'friends' => [
                        'quantity' => $request->friends['quantity'],
                        'online' => $request->friends['online']
                    ]
                ]
            );``

Comment: maybe friends should be just a relation??